# Autofocus on a custom element in angular 2

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I have an html page with html elements and my own custom component(which is a dropdown) created in angular 2.
as:

```html
<div>
<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<myDropdownComp autofocus> </myDropdownComp>
</div>
```

On pageload, focus should be on my custom dropdown component. How can I do that? I tried giving 'autofocus' which is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside your `myDropdownComp` you will need to write the custom logic in `ngOnInit` for element focus.

Comment: in this case autofocus only works when page is loaded. When we press the button next time, browser does not respect autofocus value as page is already solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, element is need to be `focusable`, to achieve this you have to set `tabIndex` attribute to element.

```
<myDropdownComp tabIndex="-1"></myDropDownComp> // now component is focusable
```

Now you can try with `autofocus` attribute, but it would be preferred to do this in `ngAfterViewInit`, to check if there is already focused element, if there is one, `blur` it, and focus this element.

```
export class MyDropdownComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   constructor(element: ElementRef) { }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (document.activeElement) {
         document.activeElement.blur();
      }
      this.element.nativeElement.focus();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run npm install angular-autofocus-fix --save  in cli

import import { AutofocusModule } from 'angular-autofocus-fix'; in your module and AutofocusModule in import section.

then you can freely use autofocus as an attribute in any tag.

or

use autofocus="true" in input tag, see updated snippet

```html
<div>
<input autofocus="true" type="text" name="fname"><br>
<myDropdownComp > </myDropdownComp>
</div>
```